# How to get ID, Name and Class of Extreme DIV from button click using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to get ID of extreme parent div?

```
<div class="panel" id="Kudapanel"> //Extreme Div
    <div class="Kudapanel1" id="Kudapanel1">
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
           <input type="button" id="yo"> //In much nestings
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Take two use cases:

- if panel classname is there in extreme div, then how to get ID of div?
- if panel classname is not there, then how to get ID of parent div?

I tried:

```
$("#yo").click(function(){
 alert($(this).closest('div').attr('id')); 
});
```

Please do not use parent().parent().parent(), as extreme div location could be different at multiple places

Comment: can you use `$(this).closest('.panel')`

Comment: Thanks, what about the second case. If panel is not there?

Comment: Have you tried using a recursive parent() function which stops at the extreme?

Comment: Yes. But i avoid that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the class selector:

```
$("#yo").click(function(){
   alert($(this).closest('div.panel').attr('id')); 
});
```

If you do not have the class we need to see the parent html where this will be located in order to give you a solution.

**UPDATE**

A solution if the class is not defined is to use another tag, instead of `div` use `section` for the upper parent tag.

```
<section id="Kudapanel"> //Extreme Div
    <div class="Kudapanel1" id="Kudapanel1">
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
           <input type="button" id="yo"> //In much nestings
         </div>
    </div>
</section> 


$("#yo").click(function(){
   alert($(this).closest('section').attr('id')); 
});
```

Comment: what if `panel ` is not available ? see  `if panel classname is not there, then how to get ID of parent div?
`

Comment: @Mivaweb
Thanks, what about the second case. If panel is not there?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer we need more html in order to give you a solution. Where will this div content be located?

Answer (score 0):

If you can count on the level of nesting, then you can just go up the parent chain until you get to it

```js
$('#yo').on('click', function(){
   alert($(this).parents().eq(2).prop('id'));  
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="panel" id="Kudapanel"> //Extreme Div
        <div class="Kudapanel1" id="Kudapanel1">
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
               <input type="button" id="yo"> //In much nestings
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Otherwise you should go with @Mivaweb's answer